# How to print the characters horizontally?

Tags: python

```
def rand_gen1():
    import random
    for i in range(8):
        print random.choice('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

The above piece of code prints a string of 8 random chars or ints or both vertically. I need it to print like `'abcd123b'` i.e. horizontally.

What changes do I need to make ?

Comment: @khelwood It would be better to concatenate though instead of printing in every iteration as SumnerEvans proposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're printing out everything on its own new line by using `print`. You can make these all into one string by storing the values in a string variable.

```
import random
def rand_gen1():
    output = ""
    for i in range(8):
        output += random.choice('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    print output
```

Answer (score 5):

Or like that (+ for Richard Neumann for importing from string):

```
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits

def rand_gen3():
    print(''.join(random.choice(ascii_lowercase + digits) for _ in range(8)))

rand_gen3()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the random choices in a string and then print the string:

```
import random

def rand_gen1():
    rand_str = ''
    for i in range(8):
        rand_str += random.choice('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    print rand_str
```

Each `print` statment creates a new line.

Answer (score 2):

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits


def rand_gen(length=8, pool=digits+ascii_lowercase):

    return ''.join(choice(pool) for _ in range(length))


print rand_gen()
```